# What things do I need to look at before buying an Xbox 360 'Jasper' Edition?

Tags: xbox-360

I am looking at buying an Xbox 360 'fat' or "Jasper" Edition second hand from a shop nearby. I have been assured it does not have the red light issue; it's on PAL.

I have no knowledge of Xbox 360 as I will be buying it for the first time. What sort of things should I check for to test whether the Xbox360 is OK to buy and does not have any issues? i.e. Temperature, Performance test, any other potential issues?

The seller has said that it has no Red Light issue and the CD-ROM works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I would obviously test it before you purchase. Due to the age of the unit, it's going to be hard to determine on the spot if you're going to run into any issues in the short or long term. Test out a few games and sign into XBL to verify the console isn't banned online.